# What is the area bounded by curve y²=4x,y axis and the line y=3.Solve using double integration.

Tags: calculus, area

> What is the area bounded by curve $y²=4x$, $y$ axis and the line $y=3$. Solve using double integration.

I operated using double integration and I am getting $9/2$ sq units but the answer to this is $9/4.$
(Using single variable integration I got $9/4.$ I am confused now, it's my first question here.)

[image: Graph]

$$A = \int _{0}^{\frac{9}{4}} \int _{0}^{2\sqrt{x}} dy \cdot dx$$
$$ =\int _{0}^{\frac{9}{4}} {2\sqrt{x}} dx \space\space=\space\space2\int _{0}^{\frac{9}{4}} {\sqrt{x}} dx$$
$$ =2\cdot\frac{2}{3}[x^{3/2}]_0 ^{\frac{9}{4}}\space\space=\space\space\frac{4}{3}\left[\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2\right]^{\frac{3}{2}}$$
$$ =\frac{4}{2}\cdot \frac{27}{8}\space\space=\space\space\frac{9}{2}\text{ sq. units}$$

Comment: You have to include your steps to get any help.

Comment: I have attached an image

Comment: Please next time don't rely on images but [type your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Your limits of integration for $y$ are incorrect. $x$ does run from 0 to  9/4, but y runs from $y=2\sqrt{x}$ to $y=3$.

Answer (score 1):

What you calculated with $A=\int_0^{9/4}\int_0^{2\sqrt x}dydx$ is not the desired area $B=\int_0^{9/4}\int_{2\sqrt x}^3dydx$ we want, but its complement in the rectangle $[0,9/4]\times[0,3],$ i.e. the area *under* the curve. You rightly found $A=9/2,$ so $B=(3\cdot9/4)-A=9/4.$